# How can I pass id to the router delete method?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a list of data shown with a delete button as below.

```
<ul class="quotes">
    <% for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) {%>
        <li class="quote" data-id= "<%= quotes[i]._id %>">
            <span><%= quotes[i].name %></span> - 
            <span><b><%= quotes[i].price %></b></span>
            <button class="delete-todo">&times;</button>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

From jQuery I am passing the id to be deleted as follow:

```
$('.delete-todo').on('click',  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parent().data('id');
    $.post('/products',{'id':id},function(data){
    },'json');
});
```

I have a product.router.js as follows:

```
router.delete(':/id',  product_controller.product_delete);
```

I am confused about how to call this delete of router and pass the id to this router method.

Comment: shouldn't you use $.ajax with `type: 'DELETE'` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NodeJS

```
router.delete('/products/:id',  product_controller.product_delete);
```

and you will get in `params`( `req.params.id`) in product_controller.product_delete function

and in JQuery

```
$('.delete-todo').on('click',  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parent().data('id');
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/products/'+ id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(data) {
            // your success response data here in data variable
            console.log('result ', data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

**Express JS**

```
router.delete('/:id',  product_controller.product_delete);

// If you are using router in `app.use('products', router)`
```

OR

```
router.delete('products/:id',  product_controller.product_delete);
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/products/'+ id,
  type: 'DELETE',
  success: callback
});
```